# Errors in C# Namespace, expected class, and end-of file expected

Tags: c#

I'm getting 4 errors with the following code, can you tell me how to fix this?

1- A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
2- Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.
3- Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

The code is:

```
License Seal;
    public void Mainform() {}

    public MainForm() {}       
    public enum auth{}
}

 {{

        Seal = new License(); 
        Seal.ID = "";
        Seal.Catch = true;
        Seal.Protection = License.Guard.FullScan;
        Seal.Initialize(); 
 }

       public MainForm.cs(); 
 }}
        auth();
        InitializeComponent();{

 }
```

Comment: What is `License Seal;` meant to mean? Your code basically makes *no* sense as C# at the moment. You haven't got a class declaration, you've got what looks like a filename as a constructor... Basically, you should start again.

Comment: And when @JonSkeet can't figure out your code, don't ever expect a computer to be able to...

Comment: You appear to have made up a new language that, whilst superficially resembling C#, doesn't seem to match it in many ways. Where did you get it from? (I'm particularly intrigued by `{{` and `}}`)

Comment: I think you really need to find some sample C# code and learn the language syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Its because all your "working" code must be inside a method, all the methods must be inside a class, and a classes must be located inside namespace (or other class).

Comment: I uploaded a .cs file which is called License. It is working code